# ("not US-")Date in Mongo DB

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I've stated with mongo db (via PHP) and have an issue with the date format.

The user will have a simple input for dates like 01.01.2016 or 31.12.2016. How should I store thous dates in mongo?

I've searched and found a way like

- Convert to ISODate date and save this date; on find() retransfer this date to dd.mm.yyyy
- Use a combination of MongoDate(strtotime("US-Date-Format"))

But I don't like to change my dd.mm.yyyy format to US and then save. On find() the same back.

If I store dd.mm.yyyy I can't sort cuz it will be handled as a string.

```
    > db.test.find({"date": {$exists: true}}).sort({date: 1}).pretty()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("572f524c8cf7decc1f0041a9"), "date" : "11.10.2016" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("572f52338cf7dea8110041ab"), "date" : "11.12.2015" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("572f521a8cf7ded51e0041aa"), "date" : "11.12.2016" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("572f523f8cf7dedf1f0041aa"), "date" : "11.12.2017" }
   { "_id" : ObjectId("572f50ab8cf7dec51f0041a9"), "date" : "12.12.2016" }
```

In mysql / postgres I would just define the date field and it would be automatically handled. Is there in mongo a same way or do I have to do it over 3 ways?

Answer (score 0):

Storing dates as ISODate is a way to go. Also there are more ways than converting date to `MongoDate(strtotime("US-Date-Format"))`, for instance you can take a look how Doctrine ODM is [handling transformation](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/c1e9777d1e083d819a354553522903b3b83a6f39/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Types/DateType.php). It's fairly easy to hide such transformation in some class handling saves.

Offhand if you're just starting your adventure with Mongo and PHP it's better to work with [new driver](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) and its [library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) as the old one is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It took me awhile to return to this problem.

Comment: I'm using now something simple like this if someone else needs a fast solution:
`
function convertToDatabaseValue($value)
    {
        ...
 return new MongoDate(strtotime($value));
    }
 
     function convertToPHPValue($value)
    {
        ...
        return date('d.m.Y', $value->sec); ;
    }`